# LIBGDX : setPasswordMode not working

Tags: libgdx, kotlin

So I am building a game in LibGDX (Kotlin) and trying to setup a username and password field.

I create my TextField

```
password = TextField("", Gui.skin)
```

I set

```
password.isPasswordMode = true (Kotin changes setter and getters, under the hode this is calling setPasswordMode)
```

However the text still appears when I enter it in the box.  I am using LibGDX 1.9.6

Comment: You also need to [set the password character](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/TextField.html#setPasswordCharacter-char-) to a character in the font. The default is 149 (bullet) which your font might not have.

Comment: Epic dude can you post as solution as it worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setPasswordMode` will enable the password display mode of a text field.

How it works is that it replaces each character with a predefined character.
By default, this is the bullet "•", which some fonts may not have.

Change the password character to something else your font does have, like "*" for example:

```
password.setPasswordCharacter('*')
```

Note that you cannot do

```
password.passwordCharacter = '*'
```

because there is no corresponding `getPasswordCharacter` method, so no Kotlin property is generated.